# Is there a way in python 2.7 to chain exceptions together and modify the return code for an exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

The problem:
I am developing test code... so naturally I have to catch exceptions everywhere.  The problem with this is that some exceptions can lead to the raising of other exceptions.  is there a way to chain exceptions together? is there a way to modify the value a chained exception will return? Is there a way to preseve/append to the stacktrace for the chained exception?

I have been looking around online, and this all seems to be possible, but I can't quite seem to find an example of all 3 being used at the same time.

Comment: by value returned, I mean the final exit code the program will exit with.

Comment: Why is this something you need to develop test code? Test code can't change how the code it's testing throws exceptions.

Comment: By test code, I mean sophisticated network software to test sophisticated network software.  Not unit tests.